# Should there be a hyphen in 're-rate'?

Tags: hyphenation, prefixes

If you have already rated something and then you want to rate it again, what is the correct term?

> *Rerate* or *Re-rate*?

Comment: What is the correct term? There is no single, correct term. One could say _reevaluate_. Also, different contexts might call for a different word. For example, say that, this morning, I wanted to change the number of stars on a Netflix movie that I reviewed last night, and, this afternoon, I wanted to make some substantial changes to a wine review I plan to submit to _Food & Wine_ magazine. I'm not sure I'd use the same word to describe both actions.

Answer (score 3):

Both are possible, though *re-rate* is more transparent and thus easier on the reader. And of course you could simply say "change rating" or "rate again", as you just did.

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable forms.

"[Rerate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/rerate?q=re-rate)" is acceptable by dictionaries. Click on the embedded hyperlink for evidence.

Though as @RegDwight stated, "re-rate" is easier to be read.